# Использование библиотеки DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста какой смысл от аннотации [DataType(DataType.Password)]?
Вот например если я использую во вью хелпер
@Html.Password
Или просто напишу у хелпера textbox new { @type = "password" }, тогда у меняпри вводе в это поле символы будут отображаться звёзлочками для безопасности пароля. А вот попробовал в модели поставить аннотацию с типпом password на свойство. Нечего такого не происходит. Так для чего же нужна эта аннотация?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataAnnotations` используется для валидации полей модели, то есть если это `Password`, то вы через аннотацию можете указать, допустим что пароль должен начинаться с заглавной буквы, минимальное/максимальное количество символов в пароле, можно указать что в пароле должны быть спец. символы и так далее.

[Валидация модели](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/22.1.php)

Пример:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(18, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[RegularExpression(@"((?=.*[a-z]+)(?=.*[A-Z]+)(?=.*[0-9]+)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+=\[{\]};:<>|./?,-]))")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

[Password DataAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699156/10384085)

[Data Annotation to validate confirm password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13237193/10384085)

При использовании системы аутентификации и авторизации ASP.NET Identity мы можем столкнуться со следующей проблемой: при вводе пароля срабатывает встроенная логика валидации, и мы эту логику никак не можем изменить, используя стандартный механим атрибутов валидации. Но что, если нам надо установить другую минимальную длину пароля т.д. И несмотря на то, что встроенная логика валидации скрыта от наших глаз, мы ее можем переопределить. За механизм валидации отвечает свойство PasswordValidator класса UserManager. Оно хранит объект валидации, который мы можем изменить.

Если мы перейдем в файл `IdentityConfig.cs` в папке `App_Start`, то в определении класса `ApplicationUserManager` мы можем увидеть применение валидатора пароля:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager
                (new UserStore<ApplicationUser>
                    (context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

//..........................

manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 6,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
    RequireDigit = true,
    RequireLowercase = true,
    RequireUppercase = true,
};
```

Для определения валидации пароля здесь применяется встроенный класс `PasswordValidator`, который имеет следующие свойства:

- `RequiredLength`: минимальная длина пароля;
- `RequireNonLetterOrDigit`: если равно true, то пароль должен будет иметь как минимум один символ, который не является алфавитно-цифровым;
- `RequireDigit`: если равно true, то пароль должен будет иметь как минимум одну цифру;
- `RequireLowercase`: если равно true, то пароль должен будет иметь как минимум один символ в нижнем регистре;
- `RequireUppercase`: если равно true, то пароль должен будет иметь как минимум один символ в верхнем регистре.

Для большинства случаев данного функционала вполне хватит, мы можем настроить минимальную длину пароля, ввод алфавитных, цифровых или неалфавитно-цифровых символов. Однако если нам потребуется более сложая логика валидации, то придется определять свой класс валидатора.

Объект валидатора представляет объект интерфейса `IIdentityValidator`. В данном случае в качестве такого объекта используется экземпляр класса `PasswordValidator`, который устанавливает минимальную длину пароля и ряд других правил. Однако больше ничего с этим валидатором мы сделать не можем. Поэтому для создания более изощренной логики валидации нам надо создать отдельный класс.

Итак, создадим следующий класс:

```
public class CustomPasswordValidator : IIdentityValidator<String>
{
    public Int32 MinRequiredLength { get; private set; } // минимальная длина

    public CustomPasswordValidator(Int32 MinRequiredLength) =>
        this.MinRequiredLength = MinRequiredLength;

    public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(String item)
    {
        var hasLowerChar = new Regex(@"[a-z]+");
        var hasUpperChar = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+");
        var hasMiniMaxChars = new Regex($@".{MinRequiredLength, 15}");
        var hasNumber = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
        var hasSymbols = new Regex(@"[!@#$%^&*()_+=\[{\]};:<>|./?,-]");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)) throw new Exception("Пароль не должен быть пустым");

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(item, hasLowerChar.ToString()))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                IdentityResult.Failed("Пароль должен содержать хотя бы одну строчную букву"));
        }
        else if (!Regex.IsMatch(item, hasUpperChar.ToString()))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                IdentityResult.Failed("Пароль должен содержать хотя бы одну заглавную букву"));
        }
        else if (!Regex.IsMatch(item, hasMiniMaxChars.ToString()))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                IdentityResult.Failed($"Пароль должен быть не менее {MinRequiredLength} символов"));
        }
        else if (!Regex.IsMatch(item, hasNumber.ToString()))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                IdentityResult.Failed("Пароль должен содержать хотя бы одно числовое значение"));
        }
        else if (!Regex.IsMatch(item, hasSymbols.ToString()))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                IdentityResult.Failed("Пароль должен содержать хотя бы один специальный символ"));
        }
        return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
    }
}
```

Класс валидатора реализует интерфейс IIdentityValidator, который имеет один метод ValidateAsync. Этот метод принимает строковый параметр, на место которого затем в программе будет передаваться строка валидируемого пароля. Он умеет  производит следующии проверки:

- Проверка пароля на пустоту;
- Проверка на содержание строчных букв;
- Проверка на содержание заглавных букв;
- Проверка на мин./макс. количество символов;
- Проверка на содержание цифр;
- Проверка на содержание спец. символов.

И затем также в определении класса ApplicationUserManager мы можем его использовать:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager
                (new UserStore<ApplicationUser>
                    (context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
//..............................
manager.PasswordValidator = new CustomPasswordValidator(5);
```

Comment: Yaroslav, хорошо а что мне мешает сделать все необходимые мне валидации, те же допустим required и range без указания что это поле является password? Я же ведь так же могу это сделать.

Comment: Yaroslav, вы дали не верный ответ, оказывается можно сделать то что я хочу и правильный ответ дали в другой теме. Оформлю как ответ.

Comment: @Андрей, ` Я же ведь так же могу это сделать.`, а я и не сказал что вы этого не можете сделать!

Comment: @Андрей, вы спросили про DataAnnotations, я ответил, но 
 Вы можете интерпретировать это как угодно. я на примере `Password` написал для чего это нужно, ну Вы вправе это делать по другом.

Comment: Yaroslav, согласен, я не совсем корректно сформулировал вопрос, вы в принципе ответили на ту формулировку что я поставил. А то что конкретно интересовало меня я дал свой ответ. Ваш тоже принимаю.

Comment: yaroslav а подскажите пожалуйста, как я раньше спрашивал разве я не могу без указания что это поле пароль, сделать те же самые валидации? И вы ещё не подскажите как сделать валидации проверки спец символов в пароле и начала с большой буквы?

Comment: можете, проверка должна быть с помощью атрибутов

Comment: А какие атрибуты нужны что бы сделать именно валидацию на необходимость в пароле спец символов и для того что бы первая буква была заглавной? Можете подсказать?

Comment: написал примерчик в ответ

Answer (score 3):

Для того что бы поле помеченное аннотацией [DataType(DataType.Password)] как пароль и при вводе в это поле значения помечались звёздочками как и должно быть в пароли нужно использовать хелпер EditorFor более подробный ответ в теме по ссылке:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044922/model-does-not-apply-datatype-password